# Downloading progress in Google Drive

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

In my Meteor server app, I am downloading a file from Google Drive using this code,

```
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/data/'+data.name);
        drive.files.get({
           fileId: data.id,
           alt: 'media',
           auth: jwtClient
        })
        .on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {

        }))
        .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log('Error during download', err);
        })
        .pipe(dest);
```

How can I get the progress of the download? For example, i want every 30 seconds to display progress of the download using console.log()

Can I use .on('data')? I am using google drive nodejs v3 provided by Google.

Comment: haven't used the Google drive SDK before but maybe you can get the file size in bytes and the bytes that the stream has processed and calculate and percentage out of that. I think though that you can't use  it that way by directly piping the read/write stream . Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-meter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get File meta (id, name, size) from drive.files.list with file name, then you can download the file.

Use 
[Node.js Quickstart for google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs) to authenticate.

I am using [progress-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-stream) to measure % data received.

```
var callAfterDownload = function (fileName, callback) {
  drive.files.list({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    pageSize: 1,
    q: 'name=\'' + fileName + '\'',
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, size)'
  }, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err)
      callback(['Error while download'])
    } else {
      var files = response.files
      //when only one file is matched we will download
      if (files.length === 1) {

        var file = files.pop()
        console.log('%s (%s)', file.name, file.id)
        var dest = fs.createWriteStream(file.name)
        var progress = Progress({time:100, length: file.size})

        //downloading matched file from drive
        drive.files.get({
          auth: oauth2Client,
          fileId: file.id,
          alt: 'media'
        }).on('error', function (err) {
          console.log('Error during download', err)
          callback(['Error while download'])
        }).pipe(progress).pipe(dest)

        //checking progress of file
        progress.on('progress', function(progress) {
          console.log('download completed ' +progress.percentage.toFixed(2) + '%')
        });

        //when write stream has finally written to file
        dest.on('finish', callback)

      } else {
        console.log('EXITING......More than one/no file exist with same name, make sure you have unique file name.')
        callback()
      }
    }
  })
}


function downloadDriveFile () {
  var fileName = 'testfile.doc'
  callAfterDownload(fileName, function (err) {
    if(err) throw err
    //your logic to do anything with the file
  })
}

downloadDriveFile();
```