# Google Drive Api v3 get download progress

Tags: node.js, download, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a download progress % for a huge file stored in my Google Drive unit when downloading from my Nodejs script.

So far I have written the code to download, which is working, however the `on('data'....)` part is never called.

```
const downloadFile = (file) => {
    const fileId = file.id;
    const fileName = path.join(basePathForStorage, file.name);
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', authorization });

    let progress = 0;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        drive.files.get(
            {
                auth: authorization,
                fileId: fileId,
                alt: 'media'
            },
            { responseType: "arraybuffer" },
            function (err, { data }) {
                
                fs.writeFile(fileName, Buffer.from(data), err => {

                    
                    // THIS PART DOES NOTHING
                    data.on('data',(d)=>{
                        progress += d.length;
                        console.log(`Progress: ${progress}`)
                    })
                    // --------------------

                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    return resolve(fileName)
                });
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Looks like I can't find the way to show the progess of the download by calling `on('data'....)`...wondering now if this is the correct way to do this, or if this is even possible.

I tried putting the `on('data'....)` code as it is now inside the `writeFile` function but also inside the callback from `drive.files.get` and nothing works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading progress in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340560/downloading-progress-in-google-drive)

Comment: @FelipeMalara, thanks, is not exactly the same promise-version as in my script, but might be of some help, thanks.

Comment: also, this solution uses a 3rd party library for progress which is not what I expect

Comment: Alright. Yeah, indeed it uses but you could set the progress using the pipe operator by yourself, without using the lib. And they are using callbacks, but you can easily promisify the operation

Comment: @FelipeMalara if you help me with a code sample would be great! will be happy to accept the answer!

Comment: Alright, lemme send a sample in here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it comes some code sample to do that, 
this example has three parts that need to be mentioned:

- Create a stream to track our download progress
- Create a method to get the file size
- Create an event emitter to send back our progress to our FE

So we will get the following:

```
const downloadFile = async(file) => {
  const fileId = file.id
  const fileName = path.join(basePathForStorage, file.name)
  
  let progress = 0
  /**
   * ATTENTION: here you shall specify where your file will be saved, usually a .temp folder
   * Here we create the stream to track our download progress
   */
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, './temp/', filename))

  const fileSize = await getFileSize(file)
  // In here we listen to the stream writing progress 
  fileStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    progress += chunk.length / fileSize
    console.log('progress', progress)
  })

  const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    authorization
  })

  drive.files.get({
    auth: authorization,
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: 'media'
  }, {
    responseType: "stream"
  },
  (err, { data }) => 
    data
      .on('end', () => console.log('onCompleted'))
      .on('error', (err) => console.log('onError', err))
      .pipe(fileStream)
  )
}
```

The method to retrieve the file size:

```
const getFileSize = ({ fileId: id }) => {
  const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    authorization
  })

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    drive.files.get({ 
      auth: authorization,
      fileId
    }, (err, metadata) {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      else resolve(metadata.size)
    })
}
```

This code sample give you the ability to get partial updates from your file download as you're creating a write stream ([nodejs#createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-write-stream/)) 
So you will be able to track your file downloading progress.

But, still you have to continuosly send these changes to your client ( FE ). 
So, you could create your own [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to track that.

And now our sample will be enchanced with the following:

In our endpoint:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

router.post('/myEndpoint', (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })

  const progressEvent = new EventEmitter()
  progressEvent.on('progress', (progress) => {
    if (progress === 100)
      res.end()
    // So, your FE side will be receiving this message continuosly
    else res.write(`{ progress: ${ progress } }`)
  })

  const file = req.body // or where you're getting your file from
  downloadFile(file, progressEvent)
})
```

In our download method:

```
const downloadFile = async(file, progressEvent) => {
  .
  .
  .
  fileStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    progress += chunk.length / fileSize
    progressEvent.emit('progress', progress)
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: thanks for your nice and extense answer! I will take some time to read it and integrate it in my code and go back!

Comment: My pleasure to help ! Okay, sure, revert to me at any case that I'll reply once available, we can move it to chat for long conversation, no problems 

Comment: Great, have an awesome new year !