# Node Google Drive Api v3 upload file progress

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-drive-api, gaxios

i want to show upload progress when uploading big files. i am using googleapis npm package, drive_v3. Same question asked for download progress and answered with [some workaround using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504263/google-drive-api-v3-get-download-progress/65505407#65505407). unfortunately i cant get it working with upload.

sample code is here

```js
// drive:drive_v3.Drive
let response = await this.drive.files.create({
    media: {
        body: buffer
    },
    fields: 'id',
}, {
    // this event is deprecated and ignored :C
    onUploadProgress(ev) {
    }
})
```

i tried onUploadProgress event, which is deprecated not working. tried some stream approach but didn't success.

Answer (score 1):

Well I managed to get upload progress on nodejs google drive api. As I said before, used a stream based workaround by using [progress_stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-stream) package.

```
let filePath = "someFilePath.zip"    
let stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
let stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

let progressable = progress_stream({ length: stat.size, time: 100, })
progressable.on("progress", (e) => {
  // progress event...
  console.log("upload progress", e.percentage)
});
stream.pipe(progressable)
let body = progressable;
            
//drive:drive_v3.Drive
let response = await this.drive.files.create({
  media: {
    body: body
})
```